# Dynamic path log4j doesn't work - problem with systemProperties

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have a problem, I want a dynamic path for my logs using log4j.

My log4j is like bellow

```
{
  "configuration": {
    "name": "Default",
    "appenders": {
      "RollingFile": {
        "name":"File",
        "fileName":"${logPath}/log-${date:yyyy-MM-dd}.log",
        "filePattern":"${logPath}/filename-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log.gz",
        "PatternLayout": {
          "pattern":"%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n"
        },
        "Policies": {
          "SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy": {
            "size":"10 MB"
          }
        },
        "DefaultRolloverStrategy": {
          "max":"10"
        }
      }
    },
    "loggers": {
      "root": {
        "level":"info",
        "appender-ref": {
          "ref":"File"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have `${logPath}` which will be dynamic depending my algorithm.

I initialize that by a function at begining.

For example:

```
private void initializeLog4j(){
    System.setProperty("logPath", "./");
}
```

But it create my logs in a directory named `${logPath}` and not at root like I want with my `setProperty`.
[image]

Someone understand my problem?
Thanks.

Comment: The problem might be that either log4j doesn't use those system properties or that the configuration has been parsed before you set the property.

Comment: You know how can I force parse after set the property? maybe it's the problem..

Comment: Is it because I use log4j2.json to configure log4j? I need to use log4j2.properties ? What is difference?

Comment: The syntax seems good to me after checking [this doc](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#Property_Substitution) (and the log4j2.json samples above). Can you try launching your JVM with -DlogPath=. to see if the variable is properly valued when the system property is specified at startup?

Comment: if I add -DlogPath=. to my compile option, and display system.property("logPath") it display "." --> it works. 
But directory is still named ${logPath}

Comment: I'm working on Intellij, I don't know if my log4j2.json file is reconized like a property file.

Comment: maybe, when it read property file, it don't recognize ${logPath} like a system property... but why?